# Mysql select the same info in multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on the database for a messaging system between users of an app. Right now all the relevant information for the messaging system is based in 2 tables. The first table contains all the information about the conversation between the two users (including the conversation id), the second is basically just a list of all the users who have access to the conversation, the third is a table of all the messages. Below is a visualization of the relevant parts of each table

Table 1:

```
|  convoId  |
-------------
|     1     |
|     2     |
|     3     |
|     4     |
|     5     |
```

Table 2:

```
|  convoId  |  userId  |
------------------------
|     1     |    4     |
|     1     |    5     |
|     2     |    4     |
|     2     |    5     |
|     2     |    6     |
|     3     |    3     |
|     3     |    4     |
```

So basically, conversation 1 is between users 4 and 5, which conversation 2 is between users 4, 5, and 6.

What I'm trying to do is, when a user goes to send a message, see if there is already a conversation between that user and the one (or ones) they are trying to message. So if user 4 was trying to message user 5, I would want to get convoId 1, but if 4 was trying to message user 7 it would create a new conversation (I've already got that part handled).

I can think of a way to do this using multiple queries and looping through them, but it seems a bit heavy handed. I was wondering if there was a way to do it in a single query (a maybe just a few).

Thanks

Comment: when 4 is trying to message 5, would you return convo 1 or 2?

Comment: As @Fabricator said can there be multiple conversation between same users?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT a.convoId 
FROM Table2 a JOIN Table2 b
ON a.convoId = b.convoId
WHERE a.userId = 4
AND b.userId = 5
AND a.convoId IN (SELECT convoId FROM Table2
                   GROUP BY convoId
                   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT userId) = 2);
```

This will return `convoId` between user 4 and 5. If no data, these users did not have any conversation yet.

Comment: should it not be table1 a.. You have joined table2 with itself.

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for. The only problem I have found is that this will pick any conversation in which those users are in, even if there are other users in it. So if the conversation was between users 4, 5, and 6 this would still select that conversation. Do you know of anyway to change this so that it will select coversations where only the users listed are in them, and no one else?